# where and when will it call email order_new.html file

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, order-email

My Simple question is:
When and where call this `order_new.html` file in core file ?

this file in `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html`

```
 {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

If call `order_new.phtml` file then it automatically call this above handle ?

this code located in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml`

```
   <!--
    Email layouts section
    -->
        <sales_email_order_items>
            <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                    <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                    <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                    <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                        <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
        </sales_email_order_items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app/code/core/Mage/Sale/Model/Order.php` line `1313` on this line he is calling the email template.

the template are define are `app/code/core/Mage/Sale/etc/config.xml` line 1.96

```
 <sales_email_order_template translate="label" module="sales">
                    <label>New Order</label>
                    <file>sales/order_new.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </sales_email_order_template>
```

Comment: My question is : where call order_new.html file ?

Comment: `app/code/core/Mage/Sale/Model/Order.php` line `1313` on this line he is calling the email template.